# What decides \$V_{ce_{max}}\$ for a BJT?

Tags: bjt

I need a BJT that is not widely available. (Don't worry about why.)

I am trying to determine if it is not manufactured because it cannot be made or if there simply isn't a lot of demand for it. If the latter, then I can either make my own or find someone to make it for me.

What decides the maximum collector-emitter voltage for a BJT? Is it the dielectric strength of silicon multiplied by the distance between the terminals, or is it something else?

Comment: Some literature: https://truenano.com/PSD20/chapter5/pdf/ch5_4_6.pdf

Comment: Usually avalanche in the collector base junction, which depends on doping density and junction thickness. Digikey have got a 1.2 kV device active and in stock, though their 2.2 kV device is obsolete.

Comment: If you're looking for high voltage high frequency types, they're not made because no one needs them anymore -- 100 to 300V, 50-1000mA, fT > 100MHz were used to drive now obsolete CRTs. A couple are still in or near production. If you aren't concerned about fT or hFE, the ultimate voltage limit for Si is quite high; BJTs should be comparable to others, and 6.6kV SCRs for example exist; it's just not practical to use BJTs instead of the devices that are available in that range (MOSFET, IGBT, SCR). Also SiC now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizontal output transistors >1kV rating eg. 2SC5149 used to be quite popular in CRT TVs. The highest voltage ones were produced for the brief duration of the large 100kg-ish (30"+) flat-screen CRT sets. So producing them in volume at a realistic cost is not a *technical* problem for those with the specialized knowledge to do so. Some info is likely available in patents, but some is undoubtedly trade secrets (possibly faded away by now).

Most consumer applications today are okay with 600-800V rating for rectified and filtered 240VAC mains applications.

If you are asking this question you probably don't qualify to have a custom transistor made, since they're pointedly not interested in small customers or small volumes of silicon acreage.

Perhaps you can use a circuit configuration with lower voltage semiconductors. Or perhaps use a thyristor as a remote-base transistor. Or something else.

That said, there are 1.2kV BJTs available off the shelf, and 2.2kV power BJTs. Not to mention 4.5kV IGBTs and MOSFETs (at a fairly steep price). And they can be stacked to increase the voltage in some cases (stacking semiconductors is how they can construct inverters for 1000kV+ DC power lines- the individual "hockey puck" thyristors may be rated at a relatively modest 8.5kV 4500A, for example)